# puppeteer count number of items in dropdown

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

My drop down looks as follow

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Which TestCafe interface do you use:</legend>
            <select id="article-header" name="preferred-interface" data-testid="preferred-interface-select">
                <option>Command Line</option>
                <option>JavaScript API</option>
                <option>Both</option>
            </select>
</fieldset>
```

I'm trying to pull the number of items (option) by next code

```
const itemsCount = await page.$$eval('fieldset > #article-header > option' , element => element.length)
console.log('List lenght =', itemsCount)
```

but from some reason the return value is 0 instead 3

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: This works for me if I use `page.setContent` on this exact HTML. What page are you scraping? Are you sure the options aren't injected with JS dynamically (hint: you can use `page.waitForSelector` or `page.waitForFunction` to wait until the options actually exist on the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ggorlen suggested , use  `waitForSelector` before the scraping